# Display result of if else function in div

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create a simple Javascript function which compares variable (which is result of previous calculation) and inputs answer to desired DIV

- if smaller than 50 -> Bad
- if between 51 and 75 -> Good
- if bigger than 75 -> Excellent

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're expected to show your work here, we're not a free coding service.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! [Right now, your question looks like a „can I haz codes?“-question](https://can-i-haz.codes) what is off-topic on SO. Either follow the steps on the first link, read **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** or visit **[the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)**. I recommend taking a JavaScript tutorial, as this is achieved very easily and should be covered at the beginning of evey JavaScript tutorial. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you guys- I will try to produce some code as I've just started with JavaScript :)

Comment: Why down this? assist share the knowledge for new developers

Answer (score 1):

I create a sample code for you base on javascript.

I updated code for display value in div.

```js
function calculate(input){
 if(input < 50) return "Bad";
 else if(input >= 51 && input <=75) return "Good";
 else if (input >=75) return "Excellent"; 
}

function showvalue(){
var mark = document.getElementById("mark").value;
//alert(calculate(mark));
var result = calculate(mark)
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mark" />
<input type="button" value="Grade" onclick="showvalue(this.value)" />

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It still looks like black magic to me, but definitely gives some insight :)!

Comment: @Hien Nguyen  Why did you pass this.value into showvalue()? showvalue() doesn't accept any input parameters and you're getting the value entered in the  box when setting up the mark variable. Removing this.value passed into showvalue() produces same result.

Comment: Yes, i want to demo difference way to use function

Comment: I'm experimenting further with this example but I don't want to create separate topic. Let's say that instead of results 'Bad' 'Good' 'Excellent' we would have numerical values like '1' '2' '3'- is there any way to use this 'return' as a part new variable, that would calculate percentage?

Comment: @David Check this out:  https://jsfiddle.net/1dq7gy5z/4/

Comment: Rich, this is amazing! Thank you so much for your time and effort!